# How can i get URL,IP Address & java Class details from error log

Tags: java, error-logging, log4j2

I am working on a big project in struts. In that for logging purpose we have used log4j1.2.12

I want that when any exception occur from code,i want following details from/of the exceptions : URL(from which exception occurs) with parameters,IP Address(from which IP my request is placed),Time Stamp,Java Class Name,Java Method Name, as well as Struts Action Name.

In my whole code, in every java file, i have used try-catch-finally.

```
public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(xyz.class);

try{
     //My Code
} catch(Exception e) {
     log.error("Exception Message :", e);
}
```

which only writes the exception details but not my required details then How can i achieve my goal?

Note: Our project has over 2000 java files in which try-catch-finally comes... So, i cant manually change/edit/modify my code in every java file.

1. So, I think i should work out of the box.!?? Am I right?
2. Is it possible that i add/change/modify some configuration in log4j.properties file and can achieve my goal?
3. Do i need to change logging framework??
4. Without touching java code, is it possible??

I will appreciate your all suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After some googling, i found that, actually my requirements leads to me a centralize error logging framework like logface or whatever. Can you suggest some good, open source (means FREE :) ) framework or softwaares?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) and [how to set up a Configrataion-File](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html). Add conversion Characters to get the value you want.
For Example:

%d{yyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss,SSS} for a full date

%l for the full qualified calling method name.